# Can't style an iframe using CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe

I created an iframe:

```
<iframe id="map"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=...
    frameborder="0" 
    style="border:0" 
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Then, in the CSS file did

```
/* The map viewer */
#map {
    height: 300
}
```

But the height did not change at all. On the other hand, if I specify the height parameter in the HTML code, the height changes properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add unit to height ie px, % etc. height:300px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a the unit value. CSS dosent know what you want 300 of.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length